# What is the advantage of using `@SequenceGenerator` vs auto increment in database?

Tags: database, hibernate, jpa

From how I understand if we have `@SequenceGenerator` annotation and a sequence name, hibernate will fetch the next value for the id by calling `nextval()` and then use that id when inserting a new entry.

Another approach would be to just mark the column as auto increment in the database and then Hibernate won't have to do this. For example with Postgres, in the column definition of the `CREATE TABLE` query

`id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY DEFAULT nextval('my_id_seq')`

What are the advantages/disadvantages of each approach? Are there specific cases when one method is preferred over the other?

Answer (score 4):

with `@SequenceGenerator`:

1. your database should support sequence !!! hence if you decided later to move from oracle to mysql -say- It wont be portable
2. may be it's a requirement in some cases to stick to sequences (an architectural decision)
3. sequence allow `allocationSize` feature which can enhance performance
4. you can use the same sequence for many tables as an ID generator (it might be an architectural decision / business requirement  also)
5. requires sequence to be created in the database ... this is a DBA action, is it allowed in your environment ?

with `Auto increment`

1. you don't have the previous pros / cons
2. direct and easy
3. but you don't have any control on the id generated or the way of generation ... it might be bad in performance (select max id , increment by one, update)

Usually in production environment , people recommend table generator as the most portable / monitor-able solution ... but it always depends

Answer (score 0):

### The Auto Strategy

[ObjectDB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ObjectDB) maintains a special global number generator for every database.

This number generator is used to generate automatic object IDs for entity objects with no primary key fields defined and the same number generator is also used to generate numeric values for primary key fields annotated by **@GeneratedValue with the AUTO strategy:**

```
@Id @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO) long id;
```

As long as you use Auto strategy, every object COMMITED to data base will receive next incremented ID from same pool.

### The Sequence Strategy

1. First big difference is that we create separate sequence which is used in chosen entites rather than having Global ObjectDB where every entity with strategy **auto** receives ID.
2. With sequence strategy, ID is generated with automatic value as soon as a new entity object is persisted (i.e. before commit). This may be useful when the primary key value is needed earlier.

My source and more in-depth artcile [HERE](https://www.objectdb.com/java/jpa/entity/generated#The_Identity_Strategy_)

Answer (score 0):

If your column have auto increment in database, you annotate that column with `@GeneratedValue` in persistant entity class which helps to auto increment while saving to the database

```
@Entity
@Table(name="s3_dominant_person")
public class S3_Dominant_Person {
 @Id
 @GeneratedValue
 private Integer id;
```

you have to `AUTO_INCREMENT` that column too in the table of database

```
's3_dominant_person', 'CREATE TABLE `s3_dominant_person` ( `id` int(11) 
NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
```